# How to use HasClass for select?

Tags: jquery

When I change the value of the `select` the `hasClass()` doesn't find the `.select_timedb` in the select so the condition is always `false`. Why is this? I use the same code for an `input` and it works fine.

I am doing this as have more then one select. When I change one of these I need to know if the select  has a `.select_timedb` class to know if I have to do something or not.

```
<select class="form-control select_time select_timedb valid" id="time1" name="time1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
   <option value="1">1 h</option>
   <option value="2">1 day</option>
</select>
```

```js
$('body').on('change', 'select_timedb', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("select_timedb")) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: remove the `.` from `select_timedb` like this `if ( $(this).hasClass( "select_timedb" ) ) {`

Comment: Typo: the class you're checking for in `hasClass()` should not have the `.` prefix. It's pretty redundant using `hasClass()` anyway as your selector ensures that only those elements are selected. The only way it would be needed would be if you're dynamically adding/removing that class, but in that case a delegated event handler would be a better idea anyway

Comment: You're already filtering my `.select_timedb` anyway, so won't all instances of this event have that class?

Comment: I doubt why are you checking hasClass in which you're binding with same class.

Comment: the dot is not the problem it doesn't work neither without the dot

Comment: @Clorge32 yes it is, and yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/co7a2bc2/. If you're still having issues then check the console for errors as there must be a mistake elsewhere in your code.

Comment: May be you want this :) https://jsfiddle.net/co7a2bc2/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 $(this).hasClass('select_timedb') // remove the .
```

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: Though you don't need to check for same class which you already bound it.

Comment: the dot is not the problem it doesn't work neither without the dot